# Can I write return NULL statement in a void function?

Tags: c++, return

What is the difference between `return`, `return 0` and `return NULL` statement?  Which `return` should I use at the end of a void function?

Comment: On a void function you can only `return;`

Comment: In C++ you can actually do: `return void();` for void functions... Which I think is fun, but just `return;` is what's expected.

Answer (score 5):

You can't return NULL in a void function,because NULL is defined by `#define NULL 0` in C++,(return 0 or NULL means that you return a value that is int or other type) void function means that it have no return value,you can write code:

`return;`

to exit a void function.

Answer (score 0):

[`NULL`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL) is a macro defined by a number of standard library headers, including `<stddef.h>`.

It is intended to represent a **null-pointer value**. It may be defined as numerical literal 0, or as `nullptr`. In the first case it can be used as an integer type value, in the second case it cannot. So it's best to only use it as a nullpointer value.

However, in modern C++ prefer to write `nullptr`, which is a built-in.

Answer (score -1):

`return;` returns nothing (`void`)

`return 0;` terminates program `0` indicating success

`return NULL;` It may be defined as `((void*)0)` in C, or `0` or `0L` in C++, `nullptr` C++11 depending on the implementation.

Comment: It doesn't depend on the compiler.In C++, NULL is defined by `#define NULL 0` in header file.

Comment: @Joe: It does depend on the implementation. And there are many more possibilities: any integral type literal 0, or `nullptr`.